# What is the most efficient way to model relational data in PyTables?

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I'm working on an application which will periodically (specifically daily) take snapshots from a large relational database, and use them to display various statistics reports for the end user. My idea is to use PyTables to store the data, as well as pandas to extract and manipulate it to prepare the reports and graphs; I'm looking for any advice on how to structure the files.

E.g. my data has a number of nested (tree-like) entities, which have a bunch of associated data, also often associated with other entities -- is it better to have individual PyTables groups for those entities, or should the structure be more flat with entities specified through specific columns with unique identifiers? Is any of those approaches more efficient, or is there perhaps a third one I haven't though of?